# How do I set font name and font size for PdfWidgetAnnotation? - iText 7.1.0 for Java

Tags: itext7

The 2 represantations of the field "fName" now are working fine. But I have no Idea how to set font name and font size for the 2 widgets. There is no font property. I tried a lot but nothing worked out. Maybe it's possible to set the standard font name and font size for the document and all created widgets?

Thanks for your help! Dirk

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.forms.PdfAcroForm;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfFormField;
import com.itextpdf.forms.fields.PdfTextFormField;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfPage;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfAnnotation;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.annot.PdfWidgetAnnotation;

public class problem5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fnPdf = "results/problem5.pdf";
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(fnPdf);
        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
        PdfPage page = pdf.addNewPage();
        PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
        // field
        PdfTextFormField field = PdfFormField.createText(pdf);
        field.setFieldName("fName");
        // widget 1
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(40, 750, 150, 20);
        PdfWidgetAnnotation widget1 = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(rect1);
        widget1.makeIndirect(pdf);
        widget1.setFlag(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        page.addAnnotation(widget1);
        field.addKid(widget1);
        // widget 2
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(240, 750, 150, 20);
        PdfWidgetAnnotation widget2 = new PdfWidgetAnnotation(rect2);
        widget2.makeIndirect(pdf);
        widget2.setFlag(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
        page.addAnnotation(widget2);
        field.addKid(widget2);
        // field
        field.setValue("Dirk");
        form.addField(field, page);
        // ----
        pdf.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fnPdf));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iText7 currently does not allow to configure different fonts and font sizes for widgets of a single text field. However, if having the same appearance is fine, then you can set font and font size for the field itself, right before setting the value. This will propagate to all the child widgets.

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(StandardFonts.COURIER);
field.setFont(font);
field.setFontSize(5);
field.setValue("Dirk");
form.addField(field, page);
```

Note that this is not the font name per se, but rather it's a `PdfFont` instance. If the font you are trying to use is not one of the standard fonts, then you have to specify the path to the font file when you are calling `PdfFontFactory.createFont`.

Comment: Thank you Alexey! That's what I was looking for and it works perfectly!